# What is AccentColor in Xcode Assets?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a simple question that chatgpt is unable to explain to me. It is `AccentColor` found in `Assets` in all Xcode Projects.

[image]

I gave it a color but I don't see any change on my app.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is like the regular color for the objects you don't specify its color.

I changed it to green and I found that the buttons in my app are now green .

[image]